# Why is my input error handling message always triggered?

Tags: java, user-input

I'm trying to make a text based menu, but any choice I currently make has it act like a nonvalid input was put in.

Here's my code (The yes output is just a check on how the if is working)

userInput is a scanner

```
System.out.println("Enter a Selection by entering an associated number: 1- deduct medicines 2-refill medicines 0-quit program");
                    if(userInput.hasNextInt())
                    {
                        selection = userInput.nextInt();
                        //TODO: Finish feature
                        if(selection == 1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Select a medication");
                            sayNames();
                            selection = userInput.nextInt();
                            //User must select a valid number of a provided medication
                            if((selection <= names.length)&&(selection > 0))
                            {
                                System.out.println("yes");
                            }
                            
                        }
                        //TODO: Finish feature
                        if(selection == 2)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Select a medication");
                            sayNames();
                        }
                        else if(selection == 0)
                        {
                            System.out.println("See you later! And don't forget to actually take your meds!");
                            quit = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("This option was not provided, please try again");
                        }
                    }
                    //If an invalid 
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("That is not a number. Please try again");
                        //Clear input to prevent infinite loop.
                        userInput.next();
                    }
```

and here's the output.

Enter a Selection by entering an associated number: 1- deduct medicines 2-refill medicines 0-quit program

1 (Input)

Select a medication

1-Fakeuprofin

2-Hooeyphin

3-Testol

4-null (from a separate error I'm working on)

1 (Input)

yes (Test output)

This option was not provided, please try again (The problem, this currently should show up if I don't press a 1, 2, or 0 but it always pops up)

Enter a Selection by entering an associated number: 1- deduct medicines 2-refill medicines 0-quit program

Can someone tell me what's going on? I tried using .next() to clear the input, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Have a look around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.util.scanner - I'm sure you'll find your answer there.

Comment: Try adding some lines to your code to help you debug it, something like `System.out.println(selection);` immediately after it's assigned might come in handy.  Or, better yet, run this in debug mode and step through it, evaluating expressions and viewing the variables.

Comment: `if(selection == 2)` should be `else if(selection == 2)`. Otherwise it continues with this block after handling the `if(selection == 1)` case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the error is being displayed is due to the *[control-flow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)* of the *selection* value.

You're current control flow is as follows.

```java
if(selection == 1)
{
    if((selection <= names.length)&&(selection > 0))
    {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }

}

if(selection == 2)
{

}
else if(selection == 0)
{

}
else
{
    System.out.println("This option was not provided, please try again");
}
```

Thus, after the *"yes"* message is printed, it will continue to the next set of conditional statements.

The solution is to add an *else* keyword before the *selection == 2* check.

```java
else if(selection == 2)
```